# Can we deactivate the use of pthread_cond_clockwait?

Tags: android, c++, c

I am working with a old Android API that does not support
`pthread_cond_clockwait` routine because this latter is introduced in API 30+ (from [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:bionic/libc/include/pthread.h;l=124-125;drc=fa658eb094d915a9640a4d0642adee7667f439e7)).
And at the same time, I am compiling and working with new version of Android that supports that routine.

I did not understand why my .so file is linking to that routine and it is not linking against it in older version. I did not change my code. I just build with old version and then new version.

So, my question is can we deactivate the use of `pthread_cond_clockwait` to execute the new binary on an old Android version?

Comment: When you build your software, if you determine that the the current, or in your case, the _target_ system does _not_ have the function, you can from `Makefile` or `cmake`, or whatever, compile and link to an additional `.c` file: `#include <pthread.h>  int pthread_cond_clockwait(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex, clockid_t clockid, const struct timespec *abstime) { return pthread_cond_timedwait(cond, mutex, abstime); }`